# Vue 3 axios get data not renders in v-for

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm getting data with axios in my property list page, the data shows in console log but never renders in my table. can anyone help with the problem?
my real sate Table body component is like:

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-for="(property , index) in propertyList" :key="index" @dblclick="gotoInfo(property.eid)">
        <td class="p-0 text-center">
          {{property.plaque}}
        </td>
        <td class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
          {{property.branchRegisterPlaque}}
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center text-sm">
                    <span class="badge badge-m bg-gradient-success p-2">
                      {{property.documentMeter}}
                    </span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          {{property.address}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
```

and how i get data and pass as props:

```
methods: {
async getProperty(page, pageSize) {
      await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet",
          {url: `folder/api/properties?page=${page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`}).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 'error') return
        this.propertyList = response.data.data.data
        this.page = response.data.data.page
        this.totalCount = response.data.data.totalCount
        console.log(response.data.data)
      })
    },
mounted() {
this.getProperty(this.page, this.pageSize)
  },
```

and

```
          <RSTable :propertyList="propertyList"/>
```

it gives me the data in console, but there's no tbody data rendered
in store, the complete form of my get is :

```
 async axiosGet({ dispatch, state }, {url}) {
  dispatch('checkAuth')
  state.loading = true
  let response
  await axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        state.loading = false
        response = {status: 'success', data: res
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        state.loading = false
        response = {status: 'error', data: error
        }})
  if (response.status === 'error') dispatch('errorHandler', response)
  return response
},
```

the screenshot of the response.data.data:
[image]

Update:
a link to my sandbox:
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-flower-31uhnw?file=/src/components/realState/RSTable.vue)

Comment: Are you sure that `response.data.data.data` is actually an array? It is not a json string that you will need to parse using `JSON.parse()` perhaps?

Comment: yes, it's an array

Comment: I'll add a screenshot of data

Comment: Do you have a props declaration inside  __RSTable__ component?

Comment: yes I have. it work ok and gives back log

Comment: The error message in your screenshot probably is why it's not continuing execution..? Something `.run` was not found apparently.

Comment: From what you've shown so far, the error's source is outside of the code you've shared. Please create a *runnable* [mcve] making sure the error is reproducible. You could safely replace the store action with `axiosGet() { return Promise.resolve({ data: someData, status: someStatus })}`. Use codesandbox.io or a similar service which provides a multi-file node-like online environment. Without a way to repro and inspect the error source, your chances of getting a useful answer are close to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If your console data is correct as you mentioned, your code should work fine. Here, I am adding a working code snippet just for a demo purpose. You can have a look and try to find out the root cause.

```js
Vue.component('rstable', {
  props: ['propertylist'],
  template: `<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(property , index) in propertylist" :key="index">
        <td class="p-0 text-center">
          {{property.plaque}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    propertyList: [{
        plaque: 'plaque 1'
    }, {
        plaque: 'plaque 2'
    }, {
        plaque: 'plaque 3'
    }, {
        plaque: 'plaque 4'
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <RSTable :propertyList="propertyList">
  </RSTable>
</div>
```